# PERL REGEX: Multiple exclusion/patterns in a single string

Tags: regex, string, perl

For some dark and mysterious matter my reg-ex is not pulling what I am expecting;

Example:

examples text to clean:

```
[PROTOCOL (Id:"hashguy82", ProcessID: 45)] 
[APP (Id:"hashguy83", ProcessID: 67)]
```

I only need to get *username*

my code is :

```
\[(PROTOCOL|APP)\s\(Id:\"(\w+)\"\, \s ProcessID\: \s \d+\)] \s
```

`(PROTOCOL|APP)` I meant  defining different possible patterns

`\s` I meant spaces

Output: no error just blank output as I guess fundamentally the format is correct but I cannot understand what I am missing.

Example String:

```
2015-01-27 00:00:09,654 TRACE  [APP (Id:"HashMap81", ProcessId: 62)] PerformanceLogger (PerformanceLogger.Python:29) - Client:344,UserId:13383,Ip:127.0.0.1,DurationMillis:272,DurationText:0.272 seconds,Path:MyClass.myMethod
```

Complete Code:

```
my $file = 'path_my_file.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";


while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = m{^
        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
        \s (WARNING|TRACE) \s\s
        qr/ \[ (?: APP| PROTOCOL) \s* \(Id:"(\w+)", \s* ProcessID: \s* \d+ \) \] /x \s
        \s PerformanceLogger \s \(PerformanceLogger\.Python\:\d+\) \s - \s
        Client:(\d+),
        UserId:(\d+),
        Ip:([\d.]+),
        DurationMillis:\d+,
        DurationText:([\d.]+) \s seconds,
        Path:/(\S+)
    $}x
    or next;

    printf('$date=%s; $level=%s; $user=%s; $client_id=%s; $user_id=%s; $ip=%s; $elapsedTime=%s; $classMethod=%s', @fields);
    print "\n";
```

Comment: Your regex looks for the string `User:`, but there is no such string in your data.

Comment: I apologise was a typo.
Corrected now:
I only need to take the values hasguy82 and hashguy83; 
let's assume like my description i have a file with two lines i need to store using my regex just the userid..eliminating everything else; i have the feeling the " in PERL is confused with something else..what do you think?

Comment: Lose the whitespaces: `\[(PROTOCOL|APP)\s\(Id:\"(\w+)\"\,\sProcessID\:\s\d+\)]\s`

Comment: Your new data has `ProcessId` where your original data has `ProcessID`. Also, your *Coomplete Code* has a Perl regex `qr/ \[ (?: GUI | SOAP ) \s* \(User:"(\w+)", \s* ThreadId: \s* \d+ \) \] /x` embedded within another regex.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use the `/x` modifier, spaces and tabs in your regex must be matched in the target string. In your pattern

```
\[(PROTOCOL|APP)\s\(Id:\"(\w+)\"\, \s ProcessID\: \s \d+\)] \s
```

you are requiring a space followed by a whitespace character after the comma. (The `\s` character class matches ASCII control characters `HT`, `LF`, `VT`, `FF`, and `CR` as well as the space character.) Likewise, after the second colon you need a space, followed by a whitespace character, followed by another space for the pattern to match. In both the cases there is only a single space in the target string so the pattern won't match. You also ask for a space followed by a whitespace character after the final close square bracket, yet your data seems to end at the bracket. Were you trying to match a terminating newline?

This would work

```
\[(PROTOCOL|APP)\s\(Id:\"(\w+)\"\,\sProcessID\:\s\d+\)]
```

but double quotes `"`, commas `,`, and colons `:` don't need escaping, and it is best to use the `/x` modifier on anything but trivial patterns so that you can add insignificant whitespace to reveal their structure. It is also best to use non-capturing parentheses `(?: ... )` around `PROTOCOL` and `APP` if you don't need to capture that part of the string.

Take a look at this program, which seems to do as you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $re = qr/ \[ (?: PROTOCOL | APP ) \s* \(Id:"(\w+)", \s* ProcessID: \s* \d+ \) \] /x;

while (<DATA>) {
  print $1, "\n" if /$re/;
}

__DATA__
[PROTOCOL (Id:"hashguy82", ProcessID: 45)] 
[APP (Id:"hashguy83", ProcessID: 67)]
```

**output**

```
hashguy82
hashguy83
```

Comment: Borodin i have added my code and a string default example in the main body of this post.... is driving me crazy it was working yesterday... :(

Comment: Your new data has `ProcessId` where your original data has `ProcessID`. Also, your *Coomplete Code* has a Perl regex `qr/ \[ (?: GUI | SOAP ) \s* \(User:"(\w+)", \s* ThreadId: \s* \d+ \) \] /x` embedded within another regex.

Comment: i changed it completely and is working

\[(APP|PROTOCOL)\s[(]Id:["](\w+)",\sprocessId:\s\d+\)]

Comment: is the solution ok? or not to elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Solution probably not elegant but is working for my purpose:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = m{^
        (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:[\d,]+)
        \s (?: WARNING | TRACE) \s\s
        \[(?: APP | PROTOCOL)\s[(]Id:["](\w+)",\sProcessID:\s\d+\)]
        \s PerformanceLogger \s \(PerformanceLogger\.Python\:\d+\) \s - \s
        Client:(\d+),
        UserId:(\d+),
        Ip:([\d.]+),
        DurationMillis:\d+,
        DurationText:([\d.]+) \s seconds,
        Path:(\S+)
    $}x
    or next;
```

Please if i am using a patching solution make me aware....